# Object recognition / image classification model

Tags: image, image-processing, tensorflow, classification

I'm looking for an image classification model such as tensorflow's inception, preferably trained.

I'm working on my dissertation project and I've already used Inception v3. I thought openCV had something like it but all I can find is mainly to detect something moving or detect a face. What I need is to give it an picture of a something and tell me what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find a pretrained model in caffe format such as: http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/pretrained/ . You can then convert it to tensorflow format using [caffe-tensorflow converter](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow).

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what's going on in this page :| . I'm an undergraduate student and I just need something to feed it an image, and give me some predictions.

Why are these .mat and what am I supposed to do with them? 
Thanks!

Comment: You may have to read some documents. You can take a look on how to read a model and run evaluation or inference: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-retrain-a-trained-model-on-the-flowers-data